# My class is being treated as an undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am attempting to compile an incomplete program to try and catch syntax issues before things get too large.  That being said, the classes that I have created are all but complete (a few member functions are stubbed), and contained in separate files from the main program.  Visual Studio recognizes them as classes (which can be seen by mousing over them).

Now, the problem is that when I try to compile this, I get the following errors:

```
1>d:\my programs\powerplay\powerplay\powerplay.hpp(99): error C2065: 'pp_player' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\my programs\powerplay\powerplay\powerplay.hpp(99): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'player'
1>d:\my programs\powerplay\powerplay\powerplay.hpp(99): error C2182: 'resolve_current_space' : illegal use of type 'void'
```

Line 99 of this file is a function declaration (where pp_player is the larger of my classes, and as stated before, recognized by VS as a class, in the editor anyway):

```
void resolve_current_space (pp_player& player);
```

Everything is properly #include 'd, and there are no problems with the other classes whatsoever.  I have tried commenting out this function (declaration and definition), but the compiler chokes on the next function that tries to use an object of this class as an argument.  I tried instantiating an object of this class earlier in the file, and while I did not get the exact same error, it more or less amounted to the same thing.

Anyone have an idea as to what this could be?  If needed, I can make the entirety of my source available if the above isn't enough.

Comment: It simply means that `pp_player` has not been declared yet. That is, there was no `class pp_player` anywhere before that function declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no declaration of `pp_player` in scope at the point you're trying to use it, plain and simple, that's what that error message means.

So, despite your assertion that everything is properly included, either that's not the case, or the things you have included do not declare or define `pp_player` before that point.

It's a basic tenet in C and C++ that most things (there are some edge cases in the standards that don't require this, such as labels) need to be declared before use.

Make sure you define the type *before* line 99 of the `hpp` file.

Comment: The class is defined in pp_player.hpp, which is #include'd in powerplay.hpp.  The #include statement for that .hpp file is the 4th non-commented line.

Comment: @Shen, there are a number of things that _could_ be wrong (little hard to tell without the full source). For one, the declaration could be within a `ifdef` that isn't "firing". Alternatively, you could be declaring `pp_player` with a `1` (wun) rather than an `l` (ell), or it could be using an older header from a different path. But the bottom line is that it's _not_ declared. Examination of the source should hopefully tell you why.

Comment: @Shen check for cyclic #includes.  Also try turning on -P to get the C pre-processor output in a .i file.

Comment: @brianbeuning thank you for reminding me to check for cyclic includes.  I had originally written the function to be a member of the class before changing my mind and taking it outside, and there was a stray #include that I forgot to remove when I moved the function.